# PostgreSQL Master Details Transaction Handling using Npgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, npgsql

Supposing I Have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE master 
master_id serial, 
master_desc character varying

CREATE TABLE details
details_masterrefid int,
details_desc character varying
CONSTRAINT master_detail_fkey(details_masterrefid)
REFERENCES master(master_id) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

Then I have a code in C# which basically will insert the header first to the master table and then loop through the details and insert it in the details table.

By doing this, I have to insert to the master table first then commit the transaction, if its successful, get the ID and use it to insert in the details table. Now, the problem is, if something went wrong in the details and the insertion is not successful, I want to rollback the data inserted on the master table. But since its already committed, I cant roll it back. It should be all or nothing. Both the master table and details table.

The only solution I can think of is by allowing the foreign key field in the details to be nullable then if everything is successful, update the foreign key field to its respective value. Any suggestion on how do it better? I dont know if its an efficient solution.

Comment: Is there something preventing you from just wrapping all the inserts on both tables in a single transaction?

Comment: The thing is, I cant. Error will occur upon inserting the data on details because of foreign key issues. Since the ID of the header is not committed yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use single statement `CTE`:

```
WITH ins1 AS (
  INSERT INTO master (cols...)
  VALUES (..)                            -- insert into master
  RETURNING master_id                    -- get generated id
)
INSERT INTO details (...)
SELECT master_id, ...                    -- insert into child table
FROM ins1;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/PNUIU65133)**

---

Another method is to wrap everything with single transaction:

```
BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO master ...

INSERT INTO child ...

COMMIT;
```

That way you will get all-or-nothing behaviour.

Comment: As I Said. Im using NPGSQL. So controlling the transaction is done in C#.

Comment: @Bigboss So use first approach. One statement (all-or-nothing)